# Accessing wrong raw resource in Android

Tags: android, resources, inputstream

I have the following code. My idea is in OnCreate, I'll populate some categories from a text file in /res/raw to my database.

First a tokenize the read file by lines (myCatToken), then each of these I split again to get the id and name.

For some reason, instead of reading rat.txt I'm getting a totally different file and I have no idea why. The file that is actually read does exist in the /res/raw folder, however its named different.

It seems that it has something to do with the resource it sends to readTxtFromRaw, however I don't see whats wrong with it.

Thanks

```
StringTokenizer myCatToken = new StringTokenizer(new String(readTxtFromRaw(R.raw.rat)));
while(myCatToken.hasMoreTokens())
{
    StringTokenizer myCatDataToken = new StringTokenizer(myCatToken.nextToken(), ",");
    String insertString = new String("insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE_CATEGORIES +
            " (" + KEY_CATEGORIES_CATID + ", " + KEY_CATEGORIES_NAME + ") values " + 
            " (" + myCatDataToken.nextToken() + ", '" + myCatDataToken.nextToken() + "')");
    db.execSQL(insertString);
}
```

For reference I include this method I'm using. mCtx is Context:

```
private String readTxtFromRaw(Integer rawResource) throws IOException
{
    InputStream inputStream = mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(rawResource);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i = inputStream.read();
    while (i != -1)
    {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
        i = inputStream.read();
    }
    inputStream.close();

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I closed Eclipse and reopened it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Clean your Workspace by going to "Project->Clean...".
So the whole project will be built again and the generated class your.package.R will be refreshed.